# chaining statements in dynamic sql in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, procedure

I came across the following syntax for procedure creation in oracle. I was wondering what are a' , q'a , q'z and z' that are used in the syntax.

Can someone please explain the usage of those constructs.

**

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "demoproc" '|| '( FIXCARD in number DEFAULT 0, INC in number DEFAULT 0 ) '|| 'AUTHID DEFINER IS '|| 'CARD NUMBER; '|| 'FOWNER VARCHAR2(128) := '|| ' SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'',''CURRENT_SCHEMA''); '|| 'BEGIN  '|| 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '|| ''' EXPLAIN PLAN FOR '' || '|| q'z q'a SELECT a' || q'a z' || q'z "demotab"."a" AS "F_NO", 
:B7 a' || q'a z' || q'z AS "P_NO" 
FROM "demotab" "demotab" 
WHERE ( 
  a' || q'a z' || q'z "demotab"."b" = :B17 AND 
  a' || q'a z' || q'z "demotab"."c" = :B2 AND 
  a' || q'a z' || q'z "demotab"."d" = :B16 
) a' ;
```

**

Note : the syntax may not be complete.

Comment: Try `sqlstr := 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...'` and then `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlstr);` in order to see the statement to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

q' '  is a way of quoting string literals with embedded quotes

e.g.

```
select q'x It's a string x' From dual;
```

`It's a string` 

 The syntax is q'[...]', where the "[" and "]" are the characters a' and z' in your example.  Therefore `select q'z execute immediate q'a SELECT count(1) from dual a'z' from dual` becomes  `execute immediate q'a SELECT count(1) from dual a'`

**Below a Sample Query**

```
-- quoting string literals (new from 10G)

select q'aIt's string with embedded quotesa' from dual -- string terminated by chacter "a"
union all
select 'It''s string with embedded quotes' from dual--quotes using a 2 quotes
union all
select q'z execute immediate q'a SELECT count(1) from dual a'z' from dual ; -- your example
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is used to treat the string between quotes exactly where it's written; you decide the character to use as delimiter and then use it in the beginning and the end of the string; some examples:

```
select 'quote here: ''' , 'double quote'from dual union all
select q'@quote here: ''@', 'q syntax, double quote means two quotes' from dual union all
select q'@quote here: '@', 'q syntax, no need fou double quotes' from dual union all
select 'two quotes here: ''''', 'same thing to have two quotes' from dual union all
select q'@two quotes here: ''@', 'and two quotes with q syntax ' from dual union all
select q'@this is the delimiter char: @.@', 'the delimiter character can be used wherever in the string' from dual union all
select q'@@delimiter is in the beginning and in the end@@', 'you have to double the delimiter if you want it in the end or beginning' from dual
```

You can see documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm)